# Identify appropriate independent feature to apply machine learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am looking to develop a machine learning algorithm to parse a sentence and identify various parts in it. Here is what I mean:

Consider the sentence '*Demonstrate me the procedure to turn on a fan when then there is no electricity*'. I would like to split the sentence into:

**Command:** 'Demonstrate'

**Action:** 'Turn on a fan'

**Condition:** 'When there is no electricity'

The way I plan to do this is by using a large number of sample inputs of sentences and specifying target outputs in each case. Then, I would use an appropriate machine learning algorithm for classification.

**The problem I am facing is with data preparation for machine learning training**. So far, I have thought about the following approach:

1- Parse the sentence and determine POS of each word. Classify each word as 1-7 depending upon the part of speech. Combine each word and the sentence will get a specific code: e.g, 102163374. Use that as an independent feature.

2- Use the total number of words as the second independent feature.

The precise problem with this approach is that the first feature will vary very heavily depending on the number of words there are in the sentence. Is that a problem? If so, how do I deal with it?

Comment: There's a couple of challenges you face. The first is that "determining the part of speech" is harder than you think because equivalent syntax trees exist for sentences (thanks to ambiguity in the language).

Second, I don't think one could build a very accurate classifier by relating position in sentence to relation to the word. You're right when you say it can vary due to input sentence length. At the least a percentage would scale with string length (first word is 0% and last is 100%), but I don't think even that is useful.

Comment: A classic case of syntactic ambiguity is "Fruit flies like a banana."  You will also have troubles with ungrammatical sentences whose intended meaning is clear enough, such as the example you give.